# Can vimgrep be used with lookaround assertions?

Tags: vim, regex-lookarounds, vimgrep

I'm trying automate some text operations on a large JavaScript project, and wish to jump to the matches using `vimgrep`, which I'll follow with various macro invocations.

My target lines look like this:

```
getText("foo", 1)
```

But, not like this:

```
getText("foo")
getText("foo", [1])
```

I only want to match usages of `getText` that have more than one parameter, which is not enclosed in an array.

This search query (<kbd>/</kbd>), which uses a negative look-ahead, seems to work:

```
getText(.*",\(.*[\)\@!
```

But, running this regular expression with `vimgrep`:

```
:vimgrep /getText(.*",\(.*[\)\@!/ project/src/**/*.js
```

...fails with this message:

```
E682: Invalid search pattern or delimiter
```

I suspect that the look-ahead part of my regex is the cause, as the error goes away when I remove it.

**Is there a way to utilize lookaround assertions with `vimgrep`?**

Comment: The literal `[` must be escaped, as it's treated as a start of "a collection" otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:vimgrep` loads each searched file into a Vim buffer and then applies Vim's regular expression search to it. So, unlike external tools as `'grepprg'` / `:grep`, you can use the full Vim regular expression syntax here.

As @Matt already commented, the `E682` is caused by failing to escape the `[`. When you use the expression in a regular `/` search, Vim just treats the `[` as a literal character, as the [collection](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2Fcollection) isn't properly closed - your search works as expected.

In [`:vimgrep`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Avimgrep), the `{pattern}` has to be enclosed by `/.../` delimiters, however. Apparently the parser continues to look for the ending `/`, but cannot find it as the not-yet closed `[` collection keeps consuming characters, and this causes the error. This inconsistency isn't nice, and it obviously made you stumble, but it's not necessarily wrong. Now you know :-)

Just properly escape the `[` character as `\[`, and it'll work:

```
:vimgrep /getText(.*",\(.*\[\)\@!/ project/src/**/*.js
```

There are special regexp atoms ([`\v`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cv) and [`\V`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5CV)) that change the amount of escaping; some people like to use them (to avoid excessive escaping, or for better readability) - I mostly find the necessary shift in interpretation distracting.

Answer (score 2):

@IngoKarkat [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58989430/438329) your question directly. However, `:vimgrep` can be slow on large projects so it would be good to have an alternative if the need arises.

#### `:grep` and `'grepprg'`

Vim's `:grep` is similar to `:vimgrep` except it uses an external program (like `grep`) to do the searching. You can even set `'grepprg'` to a [different tool](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8858/778) like: [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), [the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), or git-grep. Using these tools can often speed up searching considerably.

```
set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep
```

However, each tool uses their own regex syntax and may not provide positive/negative look-ahead/behind assertions. One way to do this is to search for all the criteria with `:grep` and then filter out the unwanted results via `:Cfilter`.

```
:grep -t js 'getText' project/src/
```

#### `:Cfilter`

`:Cfilter /{pat}/` will allow you to filter the quickfix results with a pattern. This pattern will use Vim's regex syntax so you can use your assertions as you normally would.

```
:Cfilter /getText(.*",\(.*\[\)\@!/
```

You can use `!` to negate the filter, e.g.  `:Cfilter! /{pat}/`, then entries not matching `{pat}` are used.

Note: `:Cfilter` is an optional package and you will need to do `:packadd cfilter` to load the plugin.

#### More help

For more help see:

```
:h :grep
:h 'grepprg'
:h :Cfilter
```